# Getting meta values from multiple level with json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose this is my JSON:

```
ds = [{
        "name": "groupa",
        "subGroups": [{
            "subGroup": 1,
            "people": [{
                "firstname":"Tony",
            },
            {
                "firstname":"Brian"
            }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "name": "groupb",
        "subGroups": [{
            "subGroup": 1,
            "people": [{
                "firstname":"Tony",
            },
            {
                "firstname":"Brian"
            }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

I create a Dataframe by doing:

```
df = json_normalize(ds, record_path =['subGroups', 'people'], meta=['name'])
```

This gives me:

```
    firstname   name
0   Tony    groupa
1   Brian   groupa
2   Tony    groupb
3   Brian   groupb
```

However, I'd want to also include the subGroup column.

I try:

```
df = json_normalize(ds, record_path =['subGroups', 'people'], meta=['name', 'subGroup'])
```

But that gives:

```
KeyError: 'subGroup'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
json_normalize(
   ds, 
   record_path=['subGroups', 'people'], 
   meta=[
           'name', 
           ['subGroups', 'subGroup']   # each meta field needs its own path
   ], 
   errors='ignore'
)

  firstname    name  subGroups.subGroup
0      Tony  groupa                   1
1     Brian  groupa                   1
2      Tony  groupb                   1
3     Brian  groupb                   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
df = json_normalize(ds, record_path =['subGroups', 'people'],meta['name'['subGroups', 'subGroup']])
```

Comment: It removes the "name" column as a separate column.